# Mailchimp: How to limit number of items in the RSS to Email campaign

Tags: email, mailchimp

I have my template set up to repeat a block of html between the *|RSSITEMS:|* tag, but my question is how to limit the number of times that block gets repeated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution that I've found is to use MailChimps *|FEEDITEMS|* merge tag as it offers more granular control than the *|RSSITEMS|* tag. Here's a snippet for creating a repeatable block that only pulls the 5 most recent items in an automated-RSS campaign (notice the "$count=" declaration):

```
*|FEEDBLOCK:http://website.com/feed/|* 
   <table width="600" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
       *|FEEDITEMS:[$count=5]|* 
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center"><a href="*|FEEDITEM:URL|*" target="_blank">*|FEEDITEM:TITLE|*</a></td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">*|FEEDITEM:DATE|*</td> 
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td valign="middle" align="center">*|FEEDITEM:CONTENT_FULL|*</td> 
         </tr>
       *|END:FEEDITEMS|*
   </table>
*|END:FEEDBLOCK|*
```

Comment: This solution seems to repeat the same `FEEDITEM` for me instead of iterating through all the items in the feed.

Comment: If the markup is correct, I would suggest taking a look at your RSS feed. More specifically, make sure that it validates by testing at http://feedvalidator.org/, and verify that the number of posts in your feed is equal to or greater than the FEEDITEMS $count variable in MailChimp.

Comment: If it helps, here's of one of my custom RSS templates used in WordPress for reference... http://pastebin.com/nSyjjgGV

Comment: thanks a ton @Gotequity. I messed up the markup and I was using `*|RSSITEM:XXX|*` instead of `*|FEEDITEM:XXX|*`.